# How to add a file to a zip with another filename?

Tags: rename, zip

Given a file `wrong_name.txt`, how can I add it to a zip archives `archive.zip` with an other name `right_name.txt` without modifying the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to cheat, since `zip` adds referenced files and not the symlink itself (barring the `-y` option):

```
ln -s wrong_name.txt right_name.txt
zip myzip.zip right_name.txt
rm right_name.txt wrong_name.txt
unzip myzip.zip
--> right_name.txt
```